# How to remove charset=utf8 from Content-Type header response

Tags: json, maven, spring-mvc, postman

I am using maven application with spring tools. When posting a request with postman I am getting `"Content-Type application/fhir+json;charset=UTF-8"` in my response.

I want to get `Content-Type` without `"charset=UTF-8"`.

Comment: Perhaps showing your code would help someone help you.